# Adjust the buffer size of Mediacodec's decoder on Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm decoding a H.264 stream on Android 4.2 using Mediacodec. Unfortunately, the decoder always buffers 6-10 frames, which lead to annoying latency, and Android does not provide any API to adjust buffer size. So my question is, how to modify the Android source code (or the OMX driver) in order to reduce the buffer size for realtime video streaming?

Comment: My guess is that the decoder is trying to buffer upto `DPB` size based on the `level` of the incoming stream. This strategy could be employed to handle a potential `B-frame` or `reordering` based on `POC` type. In `OMXCodec`, you could consider setting a lower number here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#1785. However, the component may very well reject it, if there is a check on minimum number of buffers required. For `ACodec`, the corresponding line is http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#578

Comment: I tried to modify the same field in ACodec before - no help. I'll try OMXCodec. Thanks!

Comment: @Ganesh: you are probably right, I know decoders do this. I just want to mention that there is absolutely no reason why they *should* do this: DPB is buffering behind, not ahead (ie: need to keep around N trailing frames, but can output current decoded frame right away).

Comment: @AlexI... I can think of a reason why decoders buffer ahead. Once a decoder starts releasing a frame, it is expected to release frames real-time i.e. every `1/fps` msec. Hence, if a decoder releases a frame immediately, then there is no guarantee that next frame would be available in `1/fps` msec if there is no buffering.

Comment: KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't.  The number of buffers in the queue is determined by the codec.  Different devices, and different codecs on the same device, can behave differently.

Unless you're using the software AVC codec, the codec implementation is provided as a binary by the hardware OEM, so there's no way to modify it (short of hex-editing).

Comment: Thanks! If nobody provides a way to modify it, I'll accept your answer.